# validation if checkbox is checked editext is not a must and if unchecked editext is must

Tags: java

I have a problem validating a checkbox and an editext linked together, If checkbox is checked editext field can be empty and if it is unchecked, editext field cannot be empty

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far and indicate which exact part of it is not working how you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code I wrote some snippets to help explain how you can accomplish this.

XML

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Check me!"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="Edit me!"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Click me!"/>
```

Java Class

```
final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
final Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

bt.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(cb.isChecked()){
            if(et.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checkbox checked and EditText empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checkbox checked and EditText not empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else{
            if(et.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checkbox not checked and EditText empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checkbox not checked and EditText not empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Hopefully you can take it from here. As you can see there are 4 different cases for the CheckBox and EditText

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Keep in mind in my code the if statements take place when the button is clicked, but you might want to check differently. Regardless, it is up to you how to handle each different case.